# Saving a file root folder in Android

Tags: android, internal-storage

So, in my app i need to save a Bitmap on the internal storage, in the "Pictures" folder for example, so that the user can see it and do whatever it wants with it later on.

It seems simple, but i can't find out how to do it. Every tutorial I find shows how to save it in the External Storage or in your app's folder, but none of how to save it on the normal, internal, public storage, avaliable for the user.

Answer (score 3):

> So, in my app i need to save a Bitmap on the internal storage, in the "Pictures" folder for example, so that the user can see it and do whatever it wants with it later on.

Then you mean external storage. The user does not have access to internal storage.

You may wish to review [the documentation for the Android definition of internal and external storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

> It seems simple, but i can't find out how to do it

You can get a likely directory via `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)`, and save the file in there. Note that there is a chance that the directory does not yet exist, so use `mkdirs()` to create it if necessary.

> Every tutorial I find shows how to save it in the External Storage or in your app's folder, but none of how to save it on the normal, internal, public storage, avaliable for the user.

That *is* external storage.